# Component only Route double rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set-up a shared Layout component for a subsection of my routing tree in react-router, but I'm having a problem where it renders the Layout component twice. It renders basically like `Layout -> Layout -> ChildComponent` instead of `Layout -> ChildComponent` like I would expect.

Routing structure and Layout component is here https://gist.github.com/UberMouse/d0cf28177516a68a7abfea8a89442dfc

I'm specifically having problems with the `/stories/new` and `/stories/show/stack|grid` routes, the layout component is the `StoriesLayout`

I've searched around as best as I can but I haven't been able to find anything on this problem, does anyone have any clues?

Comment: `<Route path="show">` why doesn't this have any component mapped to it?

Comment: Because I don't want it to render a component, it's just to put `/show/` into the URL for it's two child Routes